# PDO error with foreach and SQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tried to make a search for items in our database, here's the code.

```
$SQL = $yhteys->prepare("SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS Maara FROM TuoteTiedot 
INNER JOIN VarastoTuoteLista ON TuoteTiedot.TuoteID=VarastoTuoteLista.TuoteID 
INNER JOIN Varastopaikat ON VarastoTuoteLista.PaikkaID=Varastopaikat.PaikkaID
WHERE '?' LIKE '?' OR '?' LIKE '?'");

$SQL->execute(array($hakuvalinta1, $haku1, $hakuvalinta2, $haku2));
$tiedot = $SQL->fetchAll();
if($SQL->execute(array($haku1, $hakuvalinta1, $haku2, $hakuvalinta2))){
    if($SQL->fetchColumn() > 0){
        $SQL2 = $yhteys->prepare("SELECT * FROM TuoteTiedot 
        INNER JOIN VarastoTuoteLista ON TuoteTiedot.TuoteID=VarastoTuoteLista.TuoteID 
        INNER JOIN Varastopaikat ON VarastoTuoteLista.PaikkaID=Varastopaikat.PaikkaID
        WHERE '?'  LIKE '?' OR '?' LIKE '?'");

        $SQL2->execute(array($haku1, $hakuvalinta1, $haku2, $hakuvalinta2));
        $SQL2->fetchAll();
        foreach($yhteys->execute() as $row){ //this is line 55

            echo $row['Nimi'] + " ";
            echo $row['TuoteSeloste'] + " " ;
            echo $row['Myyntihinta'];

        }
    }
    echo "</table>";        
} else {
    echo 'Nothing found';
}
```

It gives an error on the page and it looks like this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in (removed
>   address) index.php on line 55

I have no idea what's wrong with it, but apparently the foreach doesn't like PDO or something like that. Kinda new with PDO but other people working on the site wanted to use it so I kinda have to use it too.

I've checked that the query works, and the previous executes work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody seems to have covered all the issues so I will attempt to do so.

**First:** You cannot use parameters in a query for anything other than data, no table names or column names etc.

If you think about this its quite logical. You issue the query to the database for compilation, optimization and to create an execution plan **BEFORE** you replace the parameters with data. So the database cannot compile a query if it does not know the table names and column names involved in the query.

You also do not need the single quotes around the `'?'` a simple `?` is enough

So this query will not `->prepare`

```
$SQL2 = $yhteys->prepare("SELECT * FROM TuoteTiedot 
                           INNER JOIN VarastoTuoteLista ON     
                                TuoteTiedot.TuoteID=VarastoTuoteLista.TuoteID 
                           INNER JOIN Varastopaikat ON 
                                VarastoTuoteLista.PaikkaID=Varastopaikat.PaikkaID
                          WHERE '?'  LIKE '?' OR '?' LIKE '?'");
```

You must use real column names, I dont know what your column names are so this is just an example

```
$SQL2 = $yhteys->prepare("SELECT * FROM TuoteTiedot 
                           INNER JOIN VarastoTuoteLista ON     
                                TuoteTiedot.TuoteID=VarastoTuoteLista.TuoteID 
                           INNER JOIN Varastopaikat ON 
                                VarastoTuoteLista.PaikkaID=Varastopaikat.PaikkaID
                          WHERE COLUMN1  LIKE ? OR COLUMN2 LIKE ?");
```

Now we come to your `->fetchAll()`. The `->fetchAll` returns an array containing all the rows from your result set so you need to put that data into a variable and the loop over that array

Also if you use the parameter `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` you will get an assoc array **only**, the default is an assoc array and a 0 based index as well. In other words the array returned will be double the size. This can matter in large queries.

So use

```
    $rows = $SQL2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($rows as $row){
        echo $row['Nimi'] . " ";
        echo $row['TuoteSeloste'] . " " ;
        echo $row['Myyntihinta'];

    }
```

Comment: I also solved my last problem, which was the echo. `echo $row['TuoteSeloste'] + " " ;` should be `echo $row['TuoteSeloste'] . " " ;` since php uses . for strings and not +. Thank you everyone for help. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$yhteys->execute
```

We don't `execute` PDO objects, we execute only prepared statements. `$yhteys` is an object of type `PDO`, you are correctly using prepared statements elsewhere on that object but in your foreach loop you are directly trying to call `execute` on that very `PDO` object hence the error.

Most probably you meant this

```
foreach($SQL2 as $row){
```

Comment: I don't know how to prepare it for the foreach, and have the array bind into the $SQL.

Comment: You are already putting all rows in `$SQL2` with `fetchAll` so you can just loop over that. And also check @Alex's answer about another issue with your query

Comment: Accepted the answer because it solved my biggest problem, the one that gave me the error.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to replace column names with parameters, here

```
WHERE '?'  LIKE '?' OR '?' LIKE '?'
       ^                ^
```

Table and column names cannot be replaced by parameters.

Comment: And Yep that too!, after fixing the described issue.

Comment: Okay, how am I supposed to change that then? I tried


`WHERE ".$hakuvalinta1."  LIKE '?' OR ".$hakuvalinta2." LIKE '?'`

Comment: You also do not need quotes around any of the `?` parameter markers even if the data is text!

Comment: @NikoMatikainen what happened when you tried that? did you get an error message?

Comment: No error, no return. It didn't echo any of the items at all. EDIT: one of my searches returned "005892.52005892.52005892.52", and it has NOTHING to do with my database. So something is still wrong.

Comment: I solved it. My echo used + and not . like it should.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print all data using foreach loop than you use like that:

```
$SQL2->execute(array($haku1, $hakuvalinta1, $haku2, $hakuvalinta2));
$data = $SQL2->fetchAll();
foreach($data as $row){ //this is line 55    
    echo $row['Nimi']." ";
    echo $row['TuoteSeloste']." " ;
    echo $row['Myyntihinta'];    
}
```

Comment: Plus check  @AlexAndrei Answer for the error in the SQL statement

Comment: yes i have checked and also give him a comment , Alex mentioned one issue, and i mentioned the second one. @RiggsFolly